# How to run a method that contains a for loop on button press

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple GUI app where when you input an integer, i.e "w" into a text field, it's put into the for loop, and the loop runs "w" times. When it runs, I want it to print an "X" each time the loop runs. Hopefully it'll make more sense when you see the code. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();// creating instance of JFrame

    int w = 0;

    JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(6, 37);
    JButton bSquare = new JButton("Square");// creating instance of JButton
    JButton bRATriangle = new JButton("Right Angle Triangle");
    JButton bETriangle = new JButton("Equilateral Triangle");

    bSquare.setBounds(0, 100, 200, 40);
    bRATriangle.setBounds(200, 100, 200, 40);
    bETriangle.setBounds(400, 100, 200, 40);
    textarea.setBounds(0, 500, 600, 100);
    textfield.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 80);

    textfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                int w = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText());
                textarea.setText(String.valueOf(w));
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                textarea.setText("Error!");
            } 
        }
    });

    bSquare.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                textarea.append("");
                for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                    textarea.append("X");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Be sure to describe the problems you've run into, or ask any specific questions you have.

Comment: @JornVernee Sorry, I thought I did cover what I needed. I need to know how to make a for loop when the button is pressed, and then how to print the text to the textarea.

Comment: Edit your post. Then use `final` for textfield and textarea, and in ActionListener of bSquare you should use textfield.getText() for retrieving the value entered, w is not "visible". Of course you have to parse it to Integer

Comment: It looks to me like you're already doing those things. Now, I can spot the error (although that could also be a typo in the question, so I can only guess), but other people might not, so it's important to include stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do all the logic in the action listener for the `bSquare` button. Also, you don't need to use the `int w = 0;`, since it's not properly shared across the action listeners anyway.

**Example**:

```
bSquare.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // just use a new variable here
        // default to 0 (if a NumberFormatException occurs)
        int val = 0;
        try
        {
            val = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText());
            textarea.setText(String.valueOf(val));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            textarea.setText("Error!");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < val; j++)
        {
            textarea.append("");
            for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
            {
                textarea.append("X");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks so much! But how do I create a line break? The equivalent of using System.out.println();?

Comment: No problem. For the line break, you can use: `textarea.append(System.lineSeparator());`